Working of batteries and supply of charges through them when connected to capacitors
My doubt is not really related to capacitance but about the fundamentals of working of a battery.
A capacitor with certain capacitance is charged as shown in the figure.

Please note that battery is connected to an already charged capacitor.
Now charges will flow from one metal plate to the other through the wires until potential difference between the metal plates of capacitor becomes equal to the EMF of the battery.
Final arrangement looks like this

In this process, 40 micro coulomb charge has flown.
My textbook states that battery has "supplied" a charge of 40 micro coulomb im the process. But i feel the battery just acts as a path to transfer this amount of charge from one plate to other. In this case, is there any new charge coming out of the battery? I mean is there any charge flowing due to battery's own chemical reactions, or battery simply acts as a medium to transport charge?
How does battery work in these type of circuits?
Also i would like to know why work done battery equals the change in potential energy of capacitor plus total heat produced. (This doubt is not related to the initial doubt)

Note that the net charge on the combination of both plates is +60 Coulombs both before and after being connected to the battery. So the battery has not "supplied" any charge. It has just “moved”+40 Coulombs from the right plate to the left plate. (In reality the battery moves +40 Coulombs of negative charge from left to right, as only electrons are mobile in metals).

Also i would like to know why work done battery equals the change in
potential energy of capacitor plus total heat produced. (This doubt is
not related to the initial doubt)

The charging current produces heat in the resistance of the circuit.   In this case,  since you did not show any resistance, it would primarily be the resistance of the wiring and the internal resistance of the battery.
Hope this helps.

You: is there any new charge coming out of the battery?
Ans: No new charge can't come out. The total charge of the whole system will be constant (conservation of charge). Simply you can think some electrons get deposited at anode and some electrons get out of the cathode. Actual charge of the battery's anode and cathode plate will be changed.
You: I mean is there any charge flowing due to battery's own chemical reactions, or battery simply acts as a medium to transport charge? How does battery work in these type of circuits?
Ans: To transport charge from one plate to another, battery need to react chemically. Due this chemical reaction battery will lose some of its internal energy and which is used to transport the charges (To move in the electric field charge need energy).
You: why work done by battery equals the change in potential energy of capacitor?
Ans: Avoiding rigorous calculations for energy which is derivable in this problem I can say; Battery is trying to make the same potential between the capacitor terminals with itself. Battery is losing its internal energy (in form of chemical energy) to transport the charges and store it to the capacitor, the stored energy of the capacitor increases (conservation of energy) as at last they can achieve the equilibrium (same potential).
Suggestion: revise electrostatics classes
